# Why declare UTF-8 encoding three times in a single JSP page?

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, utf-8

Why do we have UTF-8 encoding declared *three (!!!)* times in a single JSP page?

1. `contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"`
2. `pageEncoding="UTF-8"`
3. `<meta charset="UTF-8">`

Standard JSP template (HTML5):

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not expert but pageEncoding tells java to read the files as UTF-8, contentType is the resulting page header description tag, and "meta" is for the client browser to display the page.

Comment: You probably have a fourth character encoding declaration for your JSP file in an IDE project (either as an IDE default, IDE user default, project default or file-specific.) Of course, that must match `pageEncoding` since the IDE is the file writer and JSP is the file reader. It's all just clear communication across all writer-reader pairs.

Answer (score 1):

[pageEncoding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta) used for the source encoding:

> To set the source encoding of the page itself

[charset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta) used for response encoding:

> specify the encoding of the response.

Both used for JSP files.

[meta charset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta) used for the HTML:

> **charset**
>   This attribute declares the page's character encoding. It must contain a standard IANA MIME name for character encodings. Although the standard doesn't request a specific encoding, it suggests:
>
> - Authors are encouraged to use UTF-8.